# How can I make an Image in a FileImageSource format?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a picture that I want to store in my database as a file so I guess I have to use the FileImageSource to get it into the correct format.

This is my code:

```
imgPicked.Source = FileImageSourceConverter; ???
```

How would I make my imgPicked (Image in my xaml) to a fileimagesource?

Update:

Database;

```
static public async Task<bool> createData (string userId, FileImageSource thePicture )

    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", apiKey);

        var postData = new Dictionary <object, object> ();

        postData.Add ("Owner", userId);
        postData.Add ("thePicture", thePicture);

 }
```

CreateImage in database;

```
          void Click (object sender, Eventargs args)
         {
         var createResult = await parseAPI.createData 
            (Application.Current.Properties ["userId"].ToString (), imgPicked); 
//imgPicked (xaml image) gives me an error: Cannot convert "Xamarin.Forms.Image" expression to type "Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource"
         }
```

Comment: ImageSource is how you tell Forms to consume an image from a source; it only works one way.  If you want to store an image, you would store the data (file, url, stream, etc) you used to create the ImageSource in the first place.

Comment: check updated post, so the error is now when I try to create it: Cannot convert "Xamarin.Forms.Image" expression to type "Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource"

Comment: The image displayed on screen is an Image control.  You cannot store that in a database.  You need to store the file (or stream, url, etc) that was originally used to create the Image's ImageSource.

Comment: Okay. So I have to store it as an Image or ImageSource then and no fileimagesource? I store it as a "file" in my parse if that changes aything. I have tried to store it as an Image and ImageSource but cannot make it work.

Comment: Where do you originally get the jpeg from that you are displaying?  Wherever it comes from, that is the data you want to store in your db.

Comment: I get it from this function: 

http://pastebin.com/fK7i8sMt

The user picks an image from their "album", this function works fine. The problem is just that I cannot make it connect to my database.
When I do it with strings it works fine, I am having problem when I try to store Images instead.

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything.  What is cameraops?

Comment: it is from this viewmodel. http://pastebin.com/thxYM6Af

cameraOps = new CameraViewModel ();

Comment: that code works fine. it is just the saving the image to the database that is failing me

Comment: It doesn't appear that that code exposes the underlying image data to you.  You would either need to modify it, or use something like the Xamarin Media plugin: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media/

Comment: Okay. Is it easy to implement the xamarin media plugin and connect it somehow? or is it easier to modify the code?

Comment: I consider it easy - you should look at the docs and samples and try it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6n6cHfSe something like this? not sure quite how to get it right. should i code it in the end when u pick a image or in the start with my viewmodel?

Comment: trying to solve it but cannot make it work.  damn

Comment: Did you even attempt to read the docs or samples?  This is a complete replacement for the image picker you were using before.  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Media

Comment: trust me i have. iam just new so it is very hard to connect it all. if it would be possible i would rather keep my current imagepicker as it is working (worked with it for weeks to get it working!!)  and somehow add the xamarin.plugin.media and connect it all.